# JAX-RS and JAXB - Persistance configuration

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, jax-rs

I came across this sample code for the implementation of JAX-RS, with JAXB data binding. What is does is quite simple: you do a POST REST request with an XML file (customer data), which creates the customer and stored it into the customerDB MAP table. You then retrieve the customer with a GET request:

`@Path("/customers")
public class CustomerResource {
    private Map<Integer, Customer> customerDB = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Customer>();
    private AtomicInteger idCounter = new AtomicInteger();

    public CustomerResource() {
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes("application/xml")
    public Response createCustomer(Customer customer) {
        //customer.setId(idCounter.incrementAndGet());
        customerDB.put(customer.getId(), customer);

        System.out.println("Created customer " + customer.getId() + " - " + customer.getFirstName());
        System.out.println(customerDB.size());

        return Response.created(URI.create("/customers/" + customer.getId())).build();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public Customer getCustomer(@PathParam("id") int id) {
        Customer customer = customerDB.get(id);
        if (customer == null) {
            System.out.println("Customer " + id + " not found");
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        return customer;
    }`

The customer is indeed created in the customerDB map, but when you want to get it you have a null and if you check the size of the customerDB it is 0. I'm suprised this code sample which is provided in a book from a well known brand does not work. Is there anything obviously wrong?
Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The resource classes are request scoped by default, meaning a new one created for each request. In your case, since you want the db to persist, you need only a single instance for the entire application. If you register the resource class as an *instance*, that will make it a singleton. Or depending on what implementation you are using, you might be able to just annotate it with `@Singleton`.

Comment: Thanks peeskillet for the hint - using @Singleton solved it. However, would be curious to register the class as an instance.

Comment: If this is the JAX-RS book by Bill Burke (which it looks like (I have read it), there should be a chapter/section on application configuration where an `Application` subclass is used. Actually from what I recall, in the book, the author actually _does_ register the class as an instance for all the examples. It's done by adding the instance to the `Set` returned in the overridden `getSingletons()` method. All the examples are in [resteasy distribution](http://sourceforge.net/projects/resteasy/files/Resteasy%20JAX-RS/). All examples are in the oreilly-workbook dir.

Comment: Yes indeed, well spotted!